# Depth-First Search iterator implementation but allowing loops?

Tags: c#, .net-core, iterator, graph-theory, depth-first-search

## How to implement a Depth-First Search (DFS) iterator that allows loops in C#?

### Context

I was looking for an implementation of DFS on a graph to yield *individual paths* as lists of edges using [iterator methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators#enumeration-sources-with-iterator-methods), but most if not all implementations of DFS that I can find online seem to be `void` functions that simply mark vertices when they've been visited.

So I've written some code myself and while it seems to work for simple graphs, it gets caught up in loops and I'm not quite sure how to modify my code to make it work correctly.

### Graph code

My graph implementations are pretty standard, I got a generic vertex, a generic edge (no weights) and a graph that has a list of each.

#### Vertex

```cs
public class Vertex<T> : IEquatable<Vertex<T>>, IComparable<Vertex<T>>
    where T : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    public T Value ...
}
```

#### Edge

```cs
public class Edge<T> : IEquatable<Edge<T>>
    where T : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    public Vertex<T> Source ...
    public Vertex<T> Destination ...
}
```

#### Graph

```cs
public class DirectedGraph<T>
    where T : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
    public List<Vertex<T>> Vertices ...
    public List<Edge<T>> Edges ...
    public Dictionary<Vertex<T>, List<Edge<T>>> AdjacencyList ...

    public Edge<T> AddEdgeBetween(T sourceValue, T destinationValue) ...

    public Edge<T> RemoveEdgeBetween(T sourceValue, T destinationValue) ...

    public Vertex<T> AddVertex(T value) ...

    public Vertex<T> RemoveVertex(T value) ...
}
```

### Attempt at DFS iterator

My current DFS iterator looks like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<List<Edge<T>>> GetDfsPaths(Vertex<T> source)
{
    // There are no outgoing edges from the source, return an empty path and stop
    if (!AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(source))
    {
        yield return new List<Edge<T>>();
        yield break;
    }
    
    // There are outgoing edges, continue looking for paths
    foreach (Edge<T> nextEdge in AdjacencyList[source])
    {
        // Find paths from each outgoing edge
        foreach (List<Edge<T>> nextPath in GetDfsPaths(nextEdge.Destination))
        {
            // Create a new path that starts this edge
            List<Edge<T>> path = new List<Edge<T>>
            {
                nextEdge
            };

            // Add the next path from this edge to the new path and return
            path.AddRange(nextPath);
            yield return path;
        }
    }
}
```

But as I've mentioned before, I don't (know how to) check for duplicate edges so if my graph contains a loop it will throw a `StackOverflowException`. And while I do intend on using DFS to detect loops in my graphs, this isn't exactly the strategy I had in mind.

Can I somehow keep track of the currently traversed path in the recursion to check if an edge that's going to be visited is already part of the path?

### Updates

#### Adding a `HashSet<Edge<T>>` argument

```cs
public IEnumerable<List<Edge<T>>> GetDfsPaths(Vertex<T> source, HashSet<Edge<T>> visitedEdges = null)
{
    if (!AdjacencyList.ContainsKey(source))
    {
        yield return new List<Edge<T>>();
        yield break;
    }

    if (visitedEdges == null) visitedEdges = new HashSet<Edge<T>>();
    
    foreach (Edge<T> nextEdge in AdjacencyList[source])
    {
        if (!visitedEdges.Add(nextEdge)) continue;

        foreach (List<Edge<T>> nextPath in GetDfsPaths(nextEdge.Destination, visitedEdges))
        {
            List<Edge<T>> path = new List<Edge<T>>
            {
                nextEdge
            };
            path.AddRange(nextPath);
            yield return path;
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation fails for the following graph:

```
(A) → (B)
↑ ↓ ↖  ↓
(D)   (C)
```

In code:

```cs
DirectedGraph<string> graph = new();
graph.AddEdgeBetween(a, b);
graph.AddEdgeBetween(a, d);
graph.AddEdgeBetween(b, c);
graph.AddEdgeBetween(c, a);
graph.AddEdgeBetween(d, a);

var A = graph.Vertices.SingleOrDefault(v => v.Value.Equals(a));
var paths = graph.GetDfsPaths(A).ToList();
```

We would expect two paths (`ABCAD` and `ADABC`) but the method yields none.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to simply keep track of all the visited nodes. This is fairly easy to do with a `HashSet<T>`. The method should take this `visitedEdges` set as a parameter. In your outer loop you would add a check if the edge has already been visited, and if so, continue to the next edge:

```
    // There are outgoing edges, continue looking for paths
    foreach (Edge<T> nextEdge in AdjacencyList[source])
    {
         if(!visitedEdges.Add(nextEdge)){ // add returns false if the edge is already in the set
             continue;
         }
    ...
```

However, I would not recommend using *iterator blocks* for traversing trees, since it will create one iterator object for each node in the tree. I would instead suggest using an iterative solution that uses an explicit stack to keep track of nodes:

```
public static IEnumerable<(T Node, List<T> Parents)> DepthFirstLoopSafeWithFullPaths<T>(
    T self,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector,
    Maybe<IEqualityComparer<T>> equalityComparer = default)
{
    var stack = new Stack<(T Node, List<T> Path)>();
    var visited = new HashSet<T>(equalityComparer.Else(EqualityComparer<T>.Default));
    stack.Push((self, new List<T>()));
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        if (visited.Add(current.Node))
        {
            yield return current;
            foreach (var child in selector(current.Node))
            {
                if (!visited.Contains(child))
                {
                    var parentCopy = current.Path.ToList();
                    parentCopy.Add(current.Node);
                    stack.Push((child, parentCopy));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it from the graph with an extension-method

```
public static IEnumerable<(Vertex<T> Node, List<Vertex<T>> Parents)
    DepthFirstLoopSafeWithFullPaths(this DirectedGraph<T> graph, Vertex<T> root)
{    
    return DepthFirstLoopSafeWithFullPaths(
        root, 
        vertex => graph.AdjacencyList[vertex].Select(e => e.Destination)
}
public static IEnumerable<(Edge<T> Edge, List<Edge<T>> Parents)
    DepthFirstLoopSafeWithFullEdges(this DirectedGraph<T> graph, Vertex<T> root)
{    
    var rootEdges = graph.AdjacencyList[vertex]
    return rootEdges.SelectMany(rootEdge => 
        DepthFirstLoopSafeWithFullPaths(
            rootEdge , 
            edge => graph.AdjacencyList[edge.Destination])
}
```

That should give you a iterator over all the nodes in the graph, that also returns the path of vertices used to find the node. Using generics allows the same iterator to be used for arbitrary graph-representations. Using a iterative solution only requires a fixed number of objects to be created for the iteration itself, so should hopefully be a bit faster. And Since it is still an iterator block you would not traverse more of the tree than needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried the first approach with the hash set but it still trips up on loops, let me update my question.

Comment: As for your iterative solution, that certainly looks more similar to the `void` methods I've found online, but unfortunately I'm looking for something of the form `graph.DepthFirstLoopSafeWithFullPaths(source)`. Nonetheless, I was not aware of the performance consequences, so thanks!

Comment: @JansthcirlU You can add extension methods to call it using whatever format you desire. You might for example decide if you are interested in the vertices or edges.  Added an examples of this, note that the extension methods not tested, so I might have made a typo or two.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sure the iterative method works but now I'm stuck with either my original faulty implementation or an iterative implementation that I will yet again have to modify to return a path as a list of edges. I appreciate your effort but this is unfortunately not what I'm looking for.